# How to detect mulitple ANR's of the same app in /data/anr/traces.txt?

Tags: android, performance, android-anr-dialog

Being a newbie, I would like to know how to detect multiple ANR's of the same app through /data/anr/traces.txt.

I tried to create ANR manually using a crasher app. I had created almost 5 to 10 ANR's crashes. But when in pull the /data/anr/traces.txt I could find only one entry of my crasher package in traces.txt.

**ANR Crash 1 from logcat logs:**

```
06-02 00:59:15.627 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): >>>>>>>>>>>
06-02 00:59:15.627 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): ProcessName: com.nsys.android.debug.crasher
06-02 00:59:15.627 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): PID: 8423
06-02 00:59:15.627 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): annotation: executing service com.nsys.android.debug.crasher/.crasherService
```

**ANR Crash 2 from logcat logs:**

```
06-02 00:59:46.659 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): >>>>>>>>>>>
06-02 00:59:46.659 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): ProcessName: com.nsys.android.debug.crasher
06-02 00:59:46.659 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): PID: 9722
06-02 00:59:46.659 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): annotation: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
```

**ANR Crash 3 from logcat logs:**

```
06-02 01:00:05.198 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): >>>>>>>>>>>
06-02 01:00:05.198 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): ProcessName: com.nsys.android.debug.crasher
06-02 01:00:05.198 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): PID: 10006
06-02 01:00:05.198 V/SampleANRTest( 7494): annotation: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
```

**Following is the entry on traces.txt**

```
----- pid 8516 at 1970-06-02 01:10:33 -----
Cmd line: com.nsys.android.debug.crasher
Build fingerprint: ''
ABI: 'arm'
Build type: optimized
Zygote loaded classes=4685 post zygote classes=81
Intern table: 43046 strong; 137 weak
JNI: CheckJNI is off; globals=530 (plus 29 weak)
Libraries: /data/app/com.nsys.android.debug.crasher-j6WFk1kBzka9ahcpfib9YA==/lib/arm/libJNIcrasher.so /system/lib/libandroid.so /system/lib/libcompiler_rt.so /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so /system/lib/libjnigraphics.so /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so /system/lib/libqti_performance.so /system/lib/libsoundpool.so /system/lib/libwebviewchromium_loader.so libjavacore.so libopenjdk.so (11)
.
.
trimmed because of bigger stack trace
----- end 8516 -----
```

**Questions**

1) How to find the total number of ANR's crashes for a same app using /data/anr/traces.txt?

Referred this [article](http://www.programering.com/a/MDO4gjNwATg.html) to know about ANR.

Any help will be greatly helpful.